# Make xentop show memory usage in megabytes

Tags: virtualization, monitoring, xen

I'm using `xentop` to look at my xen machines and what they are doing. However it shows memory usage in KB. is there anyway to show this in MB instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is no, that's not implemented. However, you could easily modify the source code to do it. In the latest version of `tools/xenstat/xentop/xentop.c` edit [line 521](http://lxr.xensource.com/lxr/source/tools/xenstat/xentop/xentop.c#L521) and add another division by 1024.